# Unexpected Count Value in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, count

I have `file uploader`

```
<input type="file" name="photos[]" id="files" multiple="true" />
```

and I need the total no of files uploaded in uploader.

```
echo count($_FILES['photos']['name']);
```

- if I don't upload any file then result is 2.
- if I upload 1 file then result is same
- if I upload 2 file then result I got is 3

I haven't applied any increment in this.

Why this happening,I am totally confused...

Comment: It would be useful to see `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: @HoboSapiens: It returns " int 2 ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is should give a better idea on why that's happening.

When you have (for example) two of those fields and submitted it without putting any files. This is what `$_FILES` would look like:

```
Array
(
    [photos] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 
                    [1] => 
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 4
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                )

        )

)
```

So now, upon submission, your are counting `echo count($_FILES['photos']['name']);` which equates to `2`. But the fields are empty.

Inside `error` index are actually codes, and they are interpreted here:

> http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

That two `4`'s out there means:

UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE 
 Value: 4; No file was uploaded.

Comment: so isn't it show me wrong value `for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['photos']['name']); $i++) `

Comment: @AnkitChhatbar so you should check values on index `error` first before anything else. if its `0`, then just normally do your usual logic.

Comment: @AnkitChhatbar actually this part of the manual is quite useful http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php#89374